# How do I list folders with underscores first?

Tags: files, locale

So as pretty much everyone, before using Ubuntu I used a Windows machine, and one of the things I got used to in Windows was to use the underscore as the first character of a folder name as some sort of special marking so that it would be appear first on listing, both in command line and file explorer.

For instance, in my eBooks folder (in Windows) looks something like this:

```
_read
      Book1.pdf
      Book2.pdf
_reading
      Book3.pdf
Book4.pdf
Book5.pdf
```

but in Ubuntu's Nautilus it looks like this:

```
Book4.pdf
Book5.pdf    
_read
      Book1.pdf
      Book2.pdf
_reading
      Book3.pdf
```

What is happening is that it is completely ignoring the underscore and it treats "_read" as "read" and therefore not listing it in first as wished.

I have tried setting the environment variable LC_COLLATE to C. This helps somehow since it lists the underscore together, but at the end, and not at the beginning.

Thanks.

Comment: can you include a screenshot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/115741/how-do-i-force-folder-view-sort-order-to-not-ignore-special-characters although I think @maggotbrain's answer is better than the one presented there.

Comment: See: [Switch command output language from native language to english](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264283/switch-command-output-language-from-native-language-to-english)

Answer (score 22):

Since you have not specified the locale that you are currently using, this solution assumes that you are using `en_US.UTF-8` as your default.

You can check this by running the command `locale` from the command line(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>).

For example:

```
~ $ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

The variable that affects the sorting order of files is called **LC_COLLATE**.

According to the [Ubuntu help pages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale), the LC_COLLATE variable determines *"How strings (file names...) are alphabetically sorted. Using the "C" or "POSIX" locale here results in a strcmp()-like sort order, which may be preferable to language-specific locales."*

The sort order will need to be changed from `LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"` to `LC_COLLATE=C`.

From the command line(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>), enter:

`update-locale LC_COLLATE=C`

**Important: You need to log out of your system and then log back in for the changes to take effect**.

Running the `locale` command again, it should show that the `LC_COLLATE` variable has been successfully changed. Running the command `ls -l` again should reflect this change.

Comment: I have already set the LC_COLLATE to C, as I have described in the last paragraph of my question. Still, I am getting different results in both the terminal and the nautilus explorer and I have rebooted the computer in the meanwhile. Any idea why that's happening?

Comment: @nunos Do you have any aliases set for `ls` in your `.bashrc`?

Comment: @nunos Interesting. What files system type are you checking this on? The only place that I have issues with `ls -l` sorting is on an ntfs formatted drive which doesn't appear to honor the LC_COLLATE variable. All of my ext3 filesystems seem to respect that setting using the ls command as well as in Thunar and Nautilus.

Comment: that might very well be the problem then. I am using the `ls -l` command on a NTFS drive, since I have a dual boot with windows.

Comment: `update-locale LC_COLLATE=C` does not help to get folders with underscores at the top of a sorted list if you use **capital letters** at the beginning of your folder names!

Comment: In ls -l files with names beginning in an underscore in fact get sorted before file names beginning with characters. However: file names beginnign with 0...9 are sorted before file names beginning with underscore and - strangely! - a directory beginning with Ö (O-Umlaut) like Öffentlich (which is a customary thing on German installations) are sorted below all files! I don't know if this is yet another exception to what malisokan wrote before.

Comment: @AdalbertHanßen thank for mentioning digits before underscores.

Comment: if you use underscore dot then the file will be sorted before filenames beginning with digits. Perhaps this needs a special name like "put-at-front" like the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrobang.

Answer (score 1):

caja (and I think Nautilus before it) has an option in Preferences to sort folders before files. Would that help?