# Switch command output language from native language to english

Tags: command-line, locale

How can I switch the command output language from my native language to English, so I can post my Ask Ubuntu question with English command output (error messages)?

Comment: This is somewhat misleading. **It is not actually necessary for people to do this**. (If you think we should require OPs to burden themselves this way, please post on meta before instructing anyone to do so.) They can change `LANG` like this, and it might help, but we do not require *copied error messages* to be in English. We require *what the author has written* to be in English (though we usually translate it instead of closing questions). So a question written in English with Spanish terminal text is fine, while a question written in Spanish with English terminal text is not.

Comment: @EliahKagan yes, you are right, but anyway I think it is useful.

Comment: I agree, it is useful for people to be able to do this, and good you've posted this question! However, it's important people know we don't *require* them to do this (but *do* require that questions and answers themselves be written in English).

Comment: @EliahKagan On the contrary, it is very important to post **actual** error messages, and highly preferable to post them in English because that's what the main audience of this site can recognize and test. (And never, ever post a re-translated error message. Always copy-paste, because the exact wording, punctuation, even spacing can be significant.)

Answer (score 111, accepted):

`export LC_ALL=C` is enough. All subsequent command output will be in English.

More information: [What does "LC_ALL=C" do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87745/21278)

If you want to revert to the native language, unset the `LC_ALL` variable:

```
unset LC_ALL
```

Comment: Thats is problematic if you may want have output in other language than english. I did not be able to use any accentued character after this setting. https://askubuntu.com/a/818241/227400 was better.

Comment: It stops working after you close Konsole and open a new one. The new Konsole is in the old (non-English) language

Comment: See rofrol 's answer below for permanent solution

Comment: just put `export LC_ALL=C` into your `~/.bashrc` file for applying permanent changes

Answer (score 15):

### bash function for terminal

Here is my bash function to switch between DE and EN locales.

You may extend this code with your preferred languages. 
To use this, put it in your `~/.bashrc` (or `~/.bash_profile`)-

Call it with `_configure_locale EN` to switch to English.

```
function _configure_locale() { # [profile]
    local profile=${1:-EN}
    case ${profile} in
      DE|DE_DE|de_DE)
          LC_ALL="de_DE.UTF-8"
          LANG="de_DE.UTF-8"
          LANGUAGE="de_DE:de:en_US:en"
          ;;
      EN|EN_US|en|en_US)
          LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
          LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
          LANGUAGE="en_US:en"
          ;;
      *)
          echo "ALERT" "${FUNCNAME}: unknown profile '${profile}'"
          ;;
      esac
      LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"; # independent from locale
      LESSCHARSET="utf-8";    # independent from locale
      MM_CHARSET="utf-8"      # independent from locale
      echo "locale settings" "${LANG}";
      export LC_ALL LANG LANGUAGE LC_PAPER LESSCHARSET MM_CHARSET
}
```

In general I suggest to change all 3 environment variables `LC_ALL`, `LANG`, `LANGUAGE` to avoid misbehaviours of some programs.

#### Adapting to your language

Extending the code to your *native language* is quite simple.
You can find the needed values by invoking the following command

```
env |egrep -e 'LC_ALL|LANG'
```

Comment: The script needs changing for another language than German (DE)? I search for a solution independent from the native language.

Comment: @BuZZ-dEE: You can (and probably should) easily adapt this by throwing out the `case` and specifying the input to conform to the `<lang>_<country>` format. Then you can just pass it through, assuming UTF-8. If you're really keen on a tidy solution, you should probably check the user input against `locale -a` to make sure the requested locale is actually installed.

Comment: @buzz-dee: see updated answer

Answer (score 12):

Open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 bash
```

[or](https://askubuntu.com/a/264709/23878):

```
LC_ALL=C bash
```

Now the terminal output is in english language. You can check it with `locale`.

It is possible to make a command to do that with a [permanent `alias`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137726/creating-permanent-executable-aliases). Open the `.bashrc` file with your preferred editor and put the following code in there:

```
alias basheng='LANG=en_US.UTF-8 bash'
```

[or](https://askubuntu.com/a/264709/23878):

```
alias basheng='LC_ALL=C bash'
```

Restart the Bash shell. Now you have the command `basheng`. Type it in the Bash to get an english Bash shell. To leave the english shell type `exit`.

**Source:**

- [Change the Language in a Linux (BaSH) Shell](http://www.ndchost.com/wiki/server-administration/change-bash-language)
- [export LC_ALL=C](https://askubuntu.com/a/264709/23878)
- [Creating permanent executable aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137726/creating-permanent-executable-aliases)

Comment: Setting `LANG` is *not* sufficient to chance all output.

Comment: @bitmask is this: `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 && LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 && LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8 bash` better?

Comment: Actually, that should be `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8 $SHELL`.

Comment: Only *LC_ALL=C bash* work for me.

Answer (score 6):

This is configured via [locale](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man7/locale.7.html) settings, which can be set via environment variable. There are four layers of variables; the first one that is set takes precedence:

- [`LANGUAGE`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Using-gettextized-software.html#Using-gettextized-software) — don't use it, it's rarely useful and can cause bugs. Unfortunately, some versions of Ubuntu set it, so you may need to unset it.
- `LC_ALL` — overrides category-specific settings, meant primarily to be used by programs that want to run in the default locale. Not meant to be used as global settings.
- Category-specific variables beginning with `LC_`: `LC_CTYPE`, `LC_MESSAGES`, `LC_TIME`, ….
- `LANG` — sets the default locale for all categories, meant to be used in a global user settings.

The “plain” locale, with all messages untranslated, default time and number formats, ASCII as the character set, etc. is called `C`. This locale is present on every system.

Thus, to run a program with messages in English, run

```
unset LANGUAGE; LC_MESSAGES=C myprogram --option
```

or

```
unset LANGUAGE
export LC_MESSAGES=C
myprogram --option
myotherprogram
```

To run a program with all localization turned off, run

```
env -u LANGUAGE LC_ALL=C myprogram --option
```

but beware that this switches the character encoding to ASCII (so no Unicode, latin-1, etc.).

See [What should I set my locale to and what are the implications of doing so?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149111/what-should-i-set-my-locale-to-and-what-are-the-implications-of-doing-so/149129#149129) for a more detailed overview of locales.

Comment: Don't use LANGUAGE?? I don't know which OS you are on, but on Ubuntu LANGUAGE is used by default all the time via the installer and various GUIs. Which bugs are those, btw? I also read [the answer you linked to](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149111/what-should-i-set-my-locale-to-and-what-are-the-implications-of-doing-so/149129#149129), and even if it contains useful general info, the recommendation is simply not good advice on an Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson The main problem with `LANGUAGE` is that it takes precedence over `LC_ALL`, which causes bugs because programs set `LC_ALL` to get predictable output and then get confused because they aren't getting the expected output.

Comment: Well, the Ubuntu GUIs set both LANG and LANGUAGE consistently (and LC_MESSAGES inherits from LANG), which ought to prevent that kind of confusion. The reason why LANGUAGE is set is that Language Support has an interface for setting a priority list.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I know. Setting `LANGUAGE` is a bad idea nonetheless, because the benefits are very thin whereas the  bugs can be annoying and hard to find. You are right though, I should mention unsetting `LANGUAGE`.

Comment: Answers here is not a proper place to debate design issues. Such discussions are better held at e.g. [ubuntu-devel-discuss](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-devel-discuss). To be helpful to users, I really think that an answer should be based on the current design, whether you think it's optimal or not. And please note that "some versions" are all supported versions of Ubuntu desktop and derivatives, possibly with the exception of Kubuntu.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I have updated my answer to discuss `LANGUAGE`.

Comment: Saw it. So now it works at least. ;)

Answer (score 4):

in your `~/.bashrc`

```
unset LC_ALL
export LC_MESSAGES=C
```

then

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Check it

```
$ locale
LANG=pl_PL.utf8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="pl_PL.utf8"
LC_NUMERIC="pl_PL.utf8"
LC_TIME="pl_PL.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="pl_PL.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="pl_PL.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES=C
LC_PAPER="pl_PL.utf8"
LC_NAME="pl_PL.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="pl_PL.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="pl_PL.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="pl_PL.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="pl_PL.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

Why unset first?

> LC_ALL Overrides individual LC_* settings: if LC_ALL is set, none of
>   the below have any effect.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale

Comment: I don't know why this answer got downvoted. Yes it could use some more explanation, but unlike the accepted answer, it shows how to make it permanent and is more specific.

Comment: that is for my case the best answer. I want to have output in french (with full unicode, for example for commit message) but output in english. Thats is done

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to open the terminal by pressing **Alt+F2** and running this command:

```
env LANGUAGE=en gnome-terminal
```

Answer (score 1):

Related bug to language change/switching settings in Fedora(30) 
ex: ENG to Native to ENG

There is env variable that doesn't change back to EN, namely for example from Bulgarian (bg). Example:

```
# LANGUAGE=en_GB:bg
```

has to change to:

```
# LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
```

Solution(remove # and execute):

```
# export LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the gear icon on the left (system settings on Unity panel)
2. Click on Language Support
3. Select Regional Formats
4. Set your "Display numbers, dates, and currency amount ..." to English.
5. Logout the session and Login again (Required!)

Done.

Answer (score 0):

To change the terminal language to English permanently, use:

```sh
echo 'export LANG=C' >> ~/.bashrc && exec "$BASH"
```