# Problem with R installation on ubuntu after removing

Tags: software-installation

I installed R on my computer, but the version was too old so I removed it. I wanted to install another one but I couldn't. I used this command:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

I got this message:

```
Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
 r-base : Dépend: r-base-core (>= 3.3.3-1xenial0) mais ne sera pas installé
          Dépend: r-recommended (= 3.3.3-1xenial0) mais ne sera pas installé
          Recommande: r-base-html mais ne sera pas installé
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode « garder en l'état ».
```

It means that there's a problem with dependencies. How can I fix it?

Comment: English is preferred here as you will get more eyes on your post that can determine what you are asking and hopefully provide an answer If you would be so kind as to [provide the terminal output in English](http://askubuntu.com/questions/264283/switch-command-output-language-from-native-language-to-english) This would increase the likelihood of a quality answer. I'm going to attempt to answer your question, but be aware that I'm working from a translation that may or may not be accurate and [edit]ing your post as suggested will help us help you!

Comment: Close voters - [Answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/896086/225694)ed

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are missing a couple of dependencies for the R version you are attempting to install.

Specifically, [r-base-core](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=r-base-core&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) and [r-recommended](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=r-recommended&searchon=names) of versions = or greater than 3.3.1

Compatible versions are available in Ubuntu 16.10 (and beyond) by enabling the [Universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) and issuing the command

`sudo apt-get install r-base-core r-recommended`

If you are running an earlier version of Ubuntu you'll have to either upgrade to 16.10 or use a version of [R supported by your current OS](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=r-base&searchon=names).