# Help me with broken packages please

Tags: 16.04, package-management, dependencies, libraries

I have some big problems with my packages in my Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial. In the last few days I've changed my `sources.list` a lot and I've added some bunches of PPAs. Now I'm lost and don't know what to do.

I think I'm an intermediate Linux user. I started to use Debian 2 or 3 years ago, but I have problems everyday. In some months I had to format my machine more than 3 times due to problems with packages, drivers and multi-architecture.

This problem started when I tried to install VLC media player. They showed me that I have dependencies with `libgles1-mesa` and the system can't solve by itself. Then it asked me to try `apt-get -f install` to force the installation of dependencies, but my system can't solve this again.

After a lot of changes and attempts, I couldn't solve my problem, so here is some information about my status. I hope someone can help me to fix this.

I'm sorry about this, but my system is in Brazilian Portuguese. [Edit: the below is partially translated.]

`uname -a`

```
Linux Max-Notebook 4.8.0-45-generic #48~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 24 12:46:56 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`sudo apt-get install vlc`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx : Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 17.0.1+git20170319+17.0.07adc57f-0ubuntu0ricotz~xenial) but 11.2.0-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libglapi-mesa : Breaks: libglapi-mesa:i386 (!= 11.2.0-1ubuntu2) mas 17.0.1+git20170319+17.0.07adc57f-0ubuntu0ricotz~xenial está para ser instalado
 libglapi-mesa:i386 : Quebra: libglapi-mesa (!= 17.0.1+git20170319+17.0.07adc57f-0ubuntu0ricotz~xenial) mas 11.2.0-1ubuntu2 está para ser instalado
 libgles2-mesa : Depende: libglapi-mesa (= 17.0.1+git20170319+17.0.07adc57f-0ubuntu0ricotz~xenial) mas 11.2.0-1ubuntu2 está para ser instalado
 vlc : Depende: vlc-nox (= 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.1) but will not be installed
       Depende: libgles1-mesa (>= 7.8.1) mas não será instalado ou
                libgles1
       Depende: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) mas não será instalado
       Depende: libva-drm1 (>= 1.1.0) mas não será instalado
       Depende: libva-x11-1 (>= 1.0.3) mas não será instalado
       Depende: libvlccore8 (>= 2.2.0) mas não será instalado
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.1) mas não será instalado
       Recomenda: vlc-plugin-samba (= 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.1) mas não será instalado
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

`sudo apt-get -f install`

```
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências       
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
Correcting dependencies... failed.
Os pacotes a seguir têm dependências desencontradas:
 libgl1-mesa-glx : Depende: libglapi-mesa (= 17.0.1+git20170319+17.0.07adc57f-0ubuntu0ricotz~xenial) mas 11.2.0-1ubuntu2 está instalado
 libglapi-mesa : Quebra: libglapi-mesa:i386 (!= 11.2.0-1ubuntu2) mas 17.0.1+git20170319+17.0.07adc57f-0ubuntu0ricotz~xenial está instalado
 libglapi-mesa:i386 : Quebra: libglapi-mesa (!= 17.0.1+git20170319+17.0.07adc57f-0ubuntu0ricotz~xenial) mas 11.2.0-1ubuntu2 está instalado
 libgles2-mesa : Depende: libglapi-mesa (= 17.0.1+git20170319+17.0.07adc57f-0ubuntu0ricotz~xenial) mas 11.2.0-1ubuntu2 está instalado
E: Erro, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve gerou falhas, isto pode ser causado por pacotes mantidos (hold).
E: Impossível corrigir dependências
```

`cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main universe restricted
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main universe restricted
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main universe restricted
```

If you need any information just ask me.

I can't format my notebook because I'll have a lot of problems again to install and configure Android Studio, Java, Netbeans, Vagrant, Composer, Git, VirtualBox, Astah, and a lot of other softwares.

Thanks guys!

Comment: At least one of the non-Ubuntu sources you added has provided you software that is not compatible with Ubuntu 16.04. Determine which source is the problem, uninstall *ALL* packages from that source, then delete the source. The reason you keep having these package management problems is that you have not learned how packages work - once you do that, your problems will cease.

Comment: It's not a solution to your problem, but you might want to look into using btrfs, when you mess up your packages, you can easily go to an earlier state of your system, before you messed up using btrfs snapshots.

Then you can try again with a fresh start without having to reinstall and lose your programs every time.

PS: i think more people will be inclined to help if you post english error messages

Comment: @user535733 Well I think my problem is exactly this, i've installed a lot of things that i dont know where they came from, maybe i've installed some Debian 8 packages here with "dpkg -i", this is very confusing for me because I thought Debian and Ubuntu came from the same "kernel" so i'll be able to install softwares that is for Debian. Well, about your solution, i have a backup of my old sources.list, how can i remove those packages? I want to remove then all and reinstall from an official source of Ubuntu.

Comment: @smurfendrek123 I'll search about this, "btrfs", thanks! But i think it will remove more than i want. I tried to change my language to English but my system dont let me do that. When i open "Support for Languages" on Ubuntu I got this error message: "Database of Programs is corrupted. Plese use Package Manager 'Synaptic' or execute 'sudo apt-get install -f' on terminal to solve this problem first".

Comment: Have you tried running sudo apt-get install -f?

Comment: @smurfendrek123 Yes he has. See question.

Comment: @MaxVictor See [Switch command output language from native language to english](http://askubuntu.com/q/264283/301745)

Comment: Thanks 'wjandrea' and 'karel' i'll see that after try 'smurfendrek123' 's alternative. My teacher in college has the same problem, not with the same packages but he's stucked with broken packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem but i dont know exactly how, then i type "history" in my terminal, i'll paste here and try to explain what i did.

```
 1524  sudo apt-get clean
 1525  sudo apt-get autoclean
 1526  sudo apt-get -f install
 1527  sudo dpkg --configure -a
 1528  sudo apt-get -u dist-upgrade
 1529  sudo apt-get -i Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes dist-upgrade
 1530  sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes dist-upgrade
 1531  sudo apt-get remove --dry-run libglapi-mesa 
 1532  sudo apt-get remove --dry-run libgl1-mesa-glx
 1533  sudo apt-get remove --dry-run libgl1-mesa-glx -f
 1534  sudo apt-get remove --dry-run libglapi-mesa 
 1535  sudo apt-get remove --dry-run libglapi-mesa libgles2-mesa
 1536  sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
 1537  sudo apt-get autoremove --purge package-name
 1538  sudo apt-get autoremove --purge libglapi-mesa 
 1539  cd /etc/apt
 1540  cat sources.list.bkp 
 1541  sudo pluma sources.list.bkp 
 1542  sudo pluma sources.list
 1543  sudo apt-get -f install
 1544  sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
 1545  sudo apt-get purge libglapi-mesa 
 1546  sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
 1547  sudo apt-get install vlc
 1548  sudo apt-get update
 1549  cd ~
 1550  mkdir ppa-purge && cd ppa-purge && wget http://mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/ppa-purge/ppa-purge_0.2.8+bzr56_all.deb && wget http://mirror.pnl.gov/ubuntu//pool/main/a/aptitude/aptitude_0.6.6-1ubuntu1_i386.deb && sudo dpkg -i ./*.deb
 1551  sudo ppa-purge ppa:a/ppa
 1552  sudo ppa-purge ppa:me-davidsansome/ppa
 1553  sudo apt-get autoremove --purge clementine
 1554  sudo apt-get install vlc
 1555  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
 1556  mkdir y-ppa-manager && cd y-ppa-manager && wget https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/y-ppa-manager/+files/launchpad-getkeys_0.3.2-1~webupd8~oneiric_all.deb && wget https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/y-ppa-manager/+files/y-ppa-manager_0.0.8.6-1~webupd8~precise_all.deb && wget https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/y-ppa-manager/+files/yad_0.17.1.1-1~webupd8~precise_amd64.deb && dpkg -i ./*.deb
 1557  sudo apt-get -f install
 1558  cd ~
 1559  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
 1560  sudo apt-get update
 1561  sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
 1562  sudo apt-get -f install
 1563  sudo pluma /etc/apt/sources.list
 1564  sudo apt-get -f install
 1565  sudo synaptic
 1566  sudo reboot now
 1567  sudo apt-get install vlc
 1568  sudo apt autoremove
 1569  sudo apt-get install vlc
```

From line 1524~1538 i got only errors, i was trying to remove the problematic libs, then on lines 1539~1542 i've restaured my backup of sources.list because i saw in some place that i'll need the sources where i downloaded my packages.
After that i tried to install ppa-purge to remove my PPAs but my APT was broken and i cant did that.
I've downloaded PPA-Purge with WGET and tried to install with DPKG -i but i got more problems, my system said that i need to solve dependencies first.
I tried to use PPA-Purge on lines 1551 and 1552 but it didnt worked because the instalation didnt finish.
At line 1564 when i enter "apt-get -f install" it returned for me a giant list of libs and packages that will be uninstaled, about to 1,2GB then i type "N" to cancel the action because it was listed a lot of programs there, like libreoffice, compiz, apt, etc..
Then when I open Synaptic i was able to uninstall only the broken packages(libglapi-mesa, libgles1-mesa-glx..)
After this i've rebooted my PC and tried to install VLC, it goes normally and my problem was solved, i dont know how, but it was done.
After that I got another problem but i find the solution here: [Strange artifacts along window borders after waking computer from sleep mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/896221/strange-artifacts-along-window-borders-after-waking-computer-from-sleep-mode)

Well guys, i want to say thanks to all of you that spent a time to be here trying to help me. Thanks a lot, after more than 3 weeks i solved my problem and i'll try to help others with the same problem.
Sorry about my English and I hope u guys understand and learned things here. Good Luck for us, cya :)