# Weird message when installing programs

Tags: 18.10

I have Ubuntu 18.10 with KDE Plasma enviroment.

When installing a new program:

First it insalls the program and the i get this message:

```
2018/10/30 14:18:34.231310 main.go:150: description of advise-snap's
"from-apt" is lowercase: "advise-snap vil tale med apt via en apt-hook"
```

"vil tale med" is danish and means "want's to talk/connect to".

Can't find anything online.

Any help to solve this issue will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also have my system setup to Danish locale and get the same warning message. It doesn't seem to be a problem, but you can change locale for the individual command be prefixing LANG=C like so:

```
LANG=C snap refresh
```

Then you won't see the message.

You can inspect your locale settings by running:

```
locale
```

In fact you can see the effect of prefixing LANG=C by running like so:

```
LANG=C locale
```

You can change your system language more globally if you like. It's explained pretty well in this thread:
[Switch command output language from native language to english](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264283/switch-command-output-language-from-native-language-to-english)

Comment: Thanks for directing me in the right direction. Changing language in GUI did it for me.

Comment: If the answer has solved your question, please accept it by clicking on the tick/check mark (✔) to the left of the answer.