# bcl2fastq2 library installation error

Tags: command-line, software-installation

Image of message i get when trying to install bcl2fastq2 library to use with the Cellranger 3.0.1 software

[image: screenshot]

So I already installed all dependencies and checked them in terminal, but still while trying to install bcl2fast i get this, and i can't figure out what and hot toconfigure to make it install. In image it says in russian "make file not found. Help me please!

I tried to use [script from here](http://backwardincompatible.com/post/169360794395/compiling-illumina-bcl2fastq-220-on-ubuntu-with) to install bcl2fast.

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and my computer meets min sysreq for this software!

Thank you further for your help, will wait for any information that can help!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/301745). Instead, copy the text, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) to make it look nice. To get command line output in English, see instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/264283/301745). It's also important to include the exact command you ran to get that output.

Answer (score 1):

After spending a couple of hours trying everything...

I solved the issue in Ubuntu 18 downloading the .rpm package from here:
[bcl2fastq2 Conversion Software v2.20 download](https://support.illumina.com/downloads/bcl2fastq-conversion-software-v2-20.html)

Then converting to a .deb package and installing:

```
sudo alien bcl2fastq2-v2.20.0.422-Linux-x86_64.rpm
sudo dpkg -i bcl2fastq2_0v2.20.0.422-2_amd64.deb
```