# Unable to install CMake on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: apt, software-installation, 18.10, cmake

I can't install CMake on Ubuntu 18.10 because I get an error:

```
Ign.:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 4.18.0-17.18
Error:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 4.18.0-17.18
  404  Not Found [IP: 153.19.251.225 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-libc-dev_4.18.0-17.18_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 153.19.251.225 80]
```

When I try to use upgrade, I get next error:

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Failed to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem przy odlinkowywaniu pliku /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Brak dostępu)
W: Problem przy odlinkowywaniu pliku /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Brak dostępu)
```

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Have you tried `apt update` first? Can you access the IP address using `ping` or a web browser?

Comment: You should also prepend `LC_ALL=C` to your commands to get the [output in English](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264283/switch-command-output-language-from-native-language-to-english), so everyone here can understand your error messages, e.g. `LC_ALL=C sudo apt update`. You should also post the exact commands you issued along with their output.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to do an autoremove, update and then try to install cmake?

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cmake
```