# Gnome Shell broken after the latest update

Tags: gnome, updates

After the latest update I can't access the GUI on Ubuntu 22.04. When the system finished the update and restarted I'm met with a black terminal screen asking for my login and password. I've tried sudo apt update and upgrade and I'm met with:

gnome-shell: depends: gnome-shell-common (= 42.5-0ubuntu1) but 42.9-0ubuntu2 is to be installed

Recommends: gdm3 (>= 3.10.0.1-3~) but won't be installed
Recommends: ubuntu-session but won't be installed or gnome-session but won't be installed

E: impossible to fix errors, but you kept (hold) broken packages.

EDIT2: This solved my problem.
https://askubuntu.com/a/1051125/1711715

EDIT: Sudo apt update && upgrade output:

```
Hit:1 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:3 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:4 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [100kb]
Hit:5 https://dl.google.com/Linux/chrome/Deb stable InRelease
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/Ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Hit:7 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/lutris-team/lutris/Ubuntu jammy InRelease
Fetching 108kb in 1s (85,2 kb/s)
Reading package list... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
2 can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
The following packages will be kept at the current version:
 initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-core
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to removed and 2 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1477377/edit) to show us the complete output of `sudo apt update` and of `sudo apt upgrade`. The details in that output often offer important troubleshooting clues.

Comment: Sure! I'll just have to loosely translate it since my system is in another language.

Comment: Do not bother translating anything. The exact string matters. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/264283/ for how to output in english.

Comment: Done! Would it be easier to just install Ubuntu again from a live image? Would doing it so keep my files intact?

Comment: try this command `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` if  you see the package configuration screen choose ok and in second screen choose gdm3 and press enter

Comment: I see the `apt update` output. I do not see any `apt upgrade` output.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this same error in a laptop, 7 days after the original poster, and **fixed it**.

Let me explain in detail, both the analysis and the steps I took. Maybe someone can figure the causes better!

### Context and root cause

For context, this is an old laptop I hadn't used it for a few months. I applied all upgrades, and after the reboot I was left in a shell.

Tried `startx` but it didn't not work, I was getting a white message about something being broken with gnome.

The obvious fix was to just reinstall `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

It failed, because a conflict in `gnome-shell-common` version:

```
gnome-shell: depends: gnome-shell-common (= 42.5-0ubuntu1) but 42.9-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
```

This is weird! I tried to install that version, but it did not exist in the repositories:

```
apt install gnome-shell-common=42.5\*
```

### Fixing the local repos

So I got suspicious of the repositories. I was using the Spanish repositories (ES), so changed those to the standard ones:

- by opening `/etc/apt/sources.list`
- and replacing the domain:

```
# from this:
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
# to this:
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
```

After this, I run `apt update` and `apt upgrade`. And, surprise! it had many, many packages to update.

### Success!

With this new available packages, again I reinstalled `ubuntu-gnome-desktop`, and this time it worked as expected (no error message on gnome-shell

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

It worked as expected, gnome started, It's fixed, I'm happy!

FYI, I have the `gnome-shell-common` at the newest version (42.9-0ubuntu2). No idea why it was asking for an old one, I guess because of a deprecated ES repo?

### Suspicions

I'm suspicious, but have no proof, that this could be related:

- I've just updated from the **snap** store app, showed some errors
- I had gnome-tweaks and similar packages

### Conclusions

- 1. This means that **the ES locale repo was broken**, right? Is it up-to-date?
- 2. The original poster (auroravenue) has the system with the **BR locale**, maybe that repo was also wrong?