# Sorting order in Thunar: Underline first possible (with special emphasis to German sorting order)

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, thunar

This question pertains to Xubuntu 16.04 and Thunar 1.6.11

`locale – a` returns this:

```
C
C.UTF-8
de_AT.utf8
de_BE.utf8
de_CH.utf8
de_DE.utf8
de_LI.utf8
de_LU.utf8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
```

**There must be some way to have files and folders whose names start with an unterline character displayed before all other items of the same category** (files or folders, separately in each category).

In Windows this is standard rightaway and there I usually use this feature to control that some very frequently used itms are always are shown at the very beginning.

After reading a thread in the German version [forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/alphabetische-sortierung-im-dateimanager](http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/alphabetische-sortierung-im-dateimanager) I played a bit with the collating sequence (keyword LC_COLLATE) but did not achieve what I want.

Also reading [this hint](https://askubuntu.com/questions/239371/how-do-i-list-folders-with-underscores-first) which proposes to switch to `sudo update-locale LC_COLLATE=C` (which only works after logging out and in again after one has issued this command) this still has the disadvantage that it sorts file names beginning with underscore after file names starting with digits and before files starting with alphabetic characters as result of `ls -l`. In order to keep directories grouped together at the top of the listing, one has to use `ls -l --group-directories-first`.

Also the C collating sequence has the disadvantage that the usual collating order of Umlaut characters is no longer maintained. With the C collating sequence, e.g. Öffentlich goes below Vorlagen.

I guess one needs another or a modified collating sequence for German which sorts Underscore before all digits and all characters and which also sorts the Umlaut characters Ä with A, Ö with O, Ü with U, ß with s.

Is there someone in this forum who could supply us with a detailled working instruction how to achieve this goal: **Not suppress underscores at the beginning of file and folder namens when sorting them for display in Thunar** (and xfe, at which the disciussion mentioned above was targeted).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I list folders with underscores first?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/239371/how-do-i-list-folders-with-underscores-first)

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/361021/253061) over on unix/linux.