# How to edit "~/.profile" to change file sort order

Tags: command-line

I am a newbie user with a fresh install Ubuntu "Bionic Beaver" (v18.04), who has migrated from Windows 10. I want to make the file sorting order in Ubuntu match that of Windows, because that is how I have organised my (extensive) file archive. I *think* the answer lies in a post called ["How do I force folder view sort order to not ignore special characters?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115741/how-do-i-force-folder-view-sort-order-to-not-ignore-special-characters), which says:

> If you want collation to be equivalent to strcmp() sort order (i.e. do a >simple comparison of the code point values for the characters in the string), >you can switch to the legacy C locale for collation.
>
> This can be done by editing ~/.profile and adding (or modifying) a line like >the following:
>
> export LC_COLLATE=C

These instructions are too obscure for me to follow and I do not know where to find this ~/.profile, or how to edit it safely.

I hope someone will be able to give me explcit instructions on how to do this that are intelligible to someone of my inexperienced status.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Ubuntu, files that start with a `.` are hidden by default.

`~` is a symbol for your home directory located at `/home/username` (vs `C:/Documents & Settings/Username` in Windows (iirc).

This is where your Documents, Downloads, Pictures, Videos folders are. In Linux file addressing there is no leading drive name (C, D, F etc). This means that the file you are looking for is located in `/home/username/.profile`

You have two options for editing the file.

1. Visit your home directory, and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files, find `.profile` and open it with your text editor and make the changes.
2. Use the terminal and the inbuilt command-line file editor (called nano).

   - Open Terminal (I think <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> works as a shortcut)
   - Type: `nano ~/.profile`
   - Use the keypad to move your cursor to the bottom
   - Add `export LC_COLLATE=C` in a new line
   - Press  <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to exit
   - Press `Y` to confirm changes, then press `ENTER` to save.